# Bluetooth Low Energy 4.1. Channel forcing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have a product in compliance EMC testing. It uses Cypress Semiconductor CYBLE-022001-00 BLE 4.1 module. This has a raft of international approvals.
Test house is demanding that the Bluetooth module only transmit on one channel, to be defined by the tester.
Is there a way of forcing the android phone being used as the paired device to only use a given BLE channel after bonding?

Comment: When Android is central, there is no API to set the number of channels used. Maybe you can use Direct Test Mode instead, which is a standard procedure to test BLE devices.

Comment: Thanks,That's what I thought, but not what I hoped for!